# Trying to create platform-specific protobuf-net serializers with precompile from types that live in a PCL

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, protobuf-net, portable-class-library

I'm working on a cross-platform .NET project (desktop and Xamarin) that uses protobuf-net and the precompile tool extensively. I'm trying to come up with a sane way to automate and structure the protobuf code, so that the DTOs that go over the wire are shared without copy-pasting, and so the serializers can be easily regenerated in response to code changes.

Here's a simplified version of a setup I have so far:

- **PCLDTO:** A portable class library containing DTOs marked with ProtoContract, these will be serialized. Also shared with an ASP.NET backend.
- **.Net45.DTO.Lib**
- **Xam.Droid.DTO.Lib**
- **Xam.iOS.DTO.Lib:** This and above 2 are framework-specific library projects, the contents of PCLDTO are file-linked into them.
- **PBCompiler:** Console app that runs precompile on the output of the above 3 projects
- **PCLAppCore:** Business logic that interacts with the DTOs from PCLDTO, and (de)serializes them using the wrapped and injected serializers generated by PBCompiler.
- **Xam.Droid.App**
- **Xam.iOS.App**
- **.Net45.App:** This and above 2 are the final apps. They reference the platform-specific serializers produced by PBCompiler, then wrap and inject them into PCLAppCore.

The problem with this setup is that the generated serializers expect DTOs from Xam.iOS.DTO.Lib and etc, instead of PCLDTO, and I cannot reference these libraries in the app because they will conflict with the types in PCLDTO (same files are linked in), and because these assemblies are not PCL-compatible. I originally thought about using type forwarding here, but when I started digging into it, it became clear that type forwarding is not something that would work for this approach.

So, my question is - can this setup be salvaged? Otherwise, is there an alternate approach that I am overlooking? The basic requirement is to have a PCL holding DTOs from which platform-specific protobuf-net serializers can be generated with protobuf-net, and then wrapped&injected into other PCLs that reference the PCL with the DTOs.

Comment: Maybe you can create plain classes in your PCL, pass them to the native part and populate a real DTO there

Comment: Sure, but then I have more layers of "temporary" DTOs which I have to maintain, and all this mapping between DTOs has real costs at the volume of data that I'm dealing with, which I'm trying to avoid.